# Unprotect ranges by date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to manage my checksheet by using spreadsheet
Here's the sample page
[samplesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AG-YyBswujOc2wStFEstWeYkk9MQvBfqK6b16vH4yq8/edit?usp=sharing)

1. C6:AF6 is each day
2. C7:C16 ... AF7:AF16 is each day's checklist (using checkbox or enter data)
3. Protect entire sheet first, then unprotect column if date C6:AF6 matches with today, enable to enter data in that column's row (7:16)
4. Timestamp on row 17 if data's entered in every row (7:16)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please share what you have done. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also ask only one question at a time. State what is currently working among your steps and what is the next step that you can not do this is so you can focus only on one question before proceeding to the next instead of asking the community to code the whole program for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to run both of these as installable triggers.  I'm guessing you were may thinking about onOpen for the first one which Protects the sheet and unprotects the appropriate column from row 7 to 16 for each day.  The second one puts a time stamp on row 17 of that column if all of the row above it are filled.( actually I've just tested their truthiness)

```
function pSheetUpToday() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("check");//corrected spelling error
  const dt = new Date();
  const md = Utilities.formatDate(dt, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "M/d");
  const p = sh.protect();
  const rg = sh.getRange(6, 3, 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  const col = rg.createTextFinder(md).findNext().getColumn();
  const uprg = sh.getRange(7, col, 10, 1);
  p.setUnprotectedRanges([uprg]);//added square brackets
}

function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const p = sh.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  const uprg = p.getUprotectedRanges()[0];
  const col = uprg.getColumn();
  const b = uprg.getValues().flat().every(c => c);
  if(sh.getName() == "Check" && e.range.columnStart == col && b ) {
    sh.getRange(17,col).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Note: I have not tested this.

Comment: Hi, Cooper. I applied this code to my spreadsheet and it says
Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Range) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Protection.setUnprotectedRanges.
pSheetUpToday @ Code.gs:25

Comment: I annotated where I modified the code.